# Setting tick colors of matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

If I have a 3D matplotlib plot (`Axes3D` object), how do I change the color of the tick marks? I figured out how to change the color of the axis line, the tick labels, and the axis label. The obvious solution, use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')`, only changes the tick labels not the tick marks themselves.

Here is code that tries to change all the axes to red and gets everything but the tick marks:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter((0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0))
ax.w_xaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_yaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.zaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')  # only affects
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')  # tick labels
ax.tick_params(axis='z', colors='red')  # not tick marks

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The code works for me (The tick colors are all red). My matplotlib version is 1.3.1.

Comment: @Banghua I ran this in matplotlib 2.0.0 and 3.0.2 and got the same result. Something must have broken a long time ago.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [manual page](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=tick_params#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.tick_params) about `tick_params(axis='both', **kwargs)` you get a bug:

> While this function is currently implemented, the core part of the
>   Axes3D object may ignore some of these settings. Future releases will
>   fix this. Priority will be given to those who file bugs.

To override this problem use inner `_axinfo` dictionary as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711538/matplotlib-3d-axes-ticks-labels-and-latex):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.scatter((0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0))

ax.xaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='r'
ax.yaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='r'
ax.zaxis._axinfo['tick']['color']='r'
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way to achieve the expected result is as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rcParams['xtick.color'] = 'red'
rcParams['ytick.color'] = 'red'
rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = 'red'
rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = 'red'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter((0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0))
plt.show()
```

The output display is:

[image]

Comment: This code does not allow to change color of z axis separately.